# How to get notified of a state change?

Tags: contract-design, logs

I wonder if there is a way to be notified of a potential contract state change (ie it has been part of a transaction) without having to use the event mecanism.

Say I have contract that can be modified across time and I want to be able to read their constant functions if I am notified that they were changed in a transaction.

I have created the following test case

> ```
> contract Simple {
>   uint public data; // a state field
>   event Notify(uint newData);
>
>   function setData(uint _data) { data = _data; }
>   function setDataAndNotify(uint _data) { setData(_data); Notify(_data); }
> }
> ```

And on the console side, create the contract, then subscribe to the NotifyEvent or if I subscribe to any event using the filter function as follow : (S is my contract instance variable)

> ```
> S.Notify(function(e, log) { console.log("Notified ", log); })
> web3.eth.filter({ address: S.address }, function(e, log) { console.log("Generic filter ", log); })
> ```

when I call the following, both notification are received (normal)

```
S.setDataAndNotify(1, web3.callinfo)
```

when I call the following, nothing get triggered on my callback.

```
S.setData(2, web3.callinfo)
```

But the transaction went through because the S.data() returns 2.

So is there a way to still receive a callback when the S.setData() transaction is called?
I guess not but has anyone found a way (that does not imply checking after each new block with the filter('latest').

Thanks

Comment: No answer here apparently. I guess it is not feasible. I consider there is a need to have an event log added to each function then. Anyone has a better suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In absence of better solution I propose the following pattern.
Using a modifier to have all your state changing method trigger a simple small event.
That would be the inverse of the "constant" keyword.

```
contract RootContract {
    event StateChanged();
    modifier modifies() {
        _;
        StateChanged();
    }
}

contract Simple is RootContract {
  uint public data; // a state field
  event Notify(uint newData);

  function setData(uint _data) modifies { data = _data; }
}
```